# subscribe via email to incoming tfs issues?

Tags: tfs

I'm wondering if there's a way to write a tfs query such that when the results change, I will receive an email notifying me.

side question - is there a way to subscribe to updates to specific pieces of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed.  The **Alerts Explorer** appears to have pre-configured alerts for several check-in activities.  One of them is **Check-In of a specific file happens**.

And, I'm not sure which results you're talking about, but...  You can also create various alerts for Builds and Work Item actions.  I've got mine set up to alert me when something is assigned to me or when something assigned to me changes.